# Why can't I connect to local runtime? Following google's tutorial gives me syntax errors

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm running a topic modeling project and I need to run it on a much larger dataset (a 2GB xml file). The file won't upload to google drive and I decided to just try to run the code on my machine so because I need to run it faster as well. I decided to install Jupyter on my machine and tried to understand how to use my GPU on my local runtime I found another source here, where they provide a tutorial from google on how to connect to the local runtime:

[How to make Jupyter Notebook to run on GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002045/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu)

However, the very first line of code there gave me a syntax error!

```py
!pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

  File "<ipython-input-2-77e87048a5d2>", line 2
    jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand python code that well and I just want this thing to work. I don't know how to fix these syntax errors. I tried to run the other lines of code as well but all of them have syntax errors. I tried pasting that code to my original colab file on google colab and on my local copy on jupyter and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first line can be run either on a terminal or in python shell.

However, the second shell is to be run on a terminal and for this, of course, you need to have jupyter installed in your local system.

`$ jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws`

I was having this problem myself and saw this question unanswered. The above did the trick for me !