# is there a way to run code on GPUs from my terminal?

Tags: python, server, gpu

I have been using GPU acceleration sevices like Google Colab for a while, but I am not satisfied. I don't like having to write all my code in Jupyter Notebooks, and I have some other issues too. I am wondering if there is a way to get something set up where i could just run a command from my terminal, something like `upload train.py` to upload a file `train.py` to a server, and then later run `run train.py` or something like that to run it on that server, and to have the output appear in my local terminal. Does anyone know a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Yes, if you use the correct libraries and packages. Which are already available for Jupyter Notebooks, Python, R, Anaconda, or any data science environment you can think of

Comment: In fact, *Jupyter* can already do that. The *common* deployment methods use remote servers like Spark and Hadoop, not the local machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you elaborate on which libraries/packages I could use? I tried googling around a bit and didn't find anything that looked promising.

Comment: I can't guess what you tried to do or what the problem is. There are a *lot* of packages and tutorials. None of them is about "using a GPU from a terminal". All are about processing lots of data using a GPU behind the scenes. Sometimes, they're the same libraries used for scale-out processing, sometimes not

Comment: I suspect this answers your question: [How to make Jupyter Notebook to run on GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002045/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu)

Comment: `if there is a way to get something set up where i could just run a command from my terminal, something like upload train.py to upload a file train.py to a server, and then later run run train.py or something like that to run it on that server` if you are talking about running a code on the google colab server with GPU, no. As I remember they updated their policy and now you can only use the GPU on google colab via the colab notebooks. If you have a linux server with a GPU, you can connect to it via SSH and install cuda and libraries like `tensorflow_gpu` or `pytorch` and run your codes ...

Comment: ... from your terminal while logged into the server via SSH

Comment: @AkshaySehgal yeah, ssh into a linux server with a GPU would be perfect for my needs. I haven't found any good services that provide access to servers like this at a cheap price, but I guess I haven't looked enough. thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't want to use Jupyter nor do I have my own GPU, but thanks

Comment: @ChristofferCorfieldAakre I have posted my suggestions as an answer, instead of comments. do check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .. if there is a way to get something set up where I could just run a command from my terminal, something like upload train.py to upload a file train.py to a server, and then later run run train.py or something like that to run it on that server

If you are talking about running a code on the google colab server with GPU, **no**.

As I remember they updated their policy and now you can only use the GPU on google Colab via the Colab notebooks. If you have a Linux server with a GPU, you can connect to it via SSH and install Cuda and libraries like `tensorflow_gpu` or `pytorch` and run your code.

If you are looking for cheap alternatives for GPU servers, check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/maximize-your-gpu-dollars-a9133f4e546a) and [this](https://becominghuman.ai/heroku-for-deep-learning-floydhub-6bbc0fb6a77e) link.

`Heroku` is a non-GPU alternative where you can prototype your codes and then use any of the cloud providers such as AWS or Google Cloud. (As I remember AWS provides a decent number of free hours of GPU time at signup).

Then there is another [alternative](https://becominghuman.ai/heroku-for-deep-learning-floydhub-6bbc0fb6a77e) called **FloydHub** that I have heard people call `heroku for deep learning`. I haven't used it personally but this might also be what you are looking for.

---

On a personal note, even though it's not that efficient. I prototype my codes locally and then upload them to my google drive and do the final training on google Colab GPU. It's an unnecessary step, but that's the best I could find without renting a server.