# Switching from CPU to GPU in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, gpu

```
%%time
%run ./DeepRecommender/data_utils/netflix_data_convert.py training_set NF_DATA
```

I am trying to run these commands in a cell in Jupyter Notebook. But I would like to make this process run on my GPU (Nvidia GTX 1050Ti 4GB-laptop) since it is computationally very expensive. I have installed CUDA Toolkit properly, I have verified it.

My question differs from the [How to make Jupyter Notebook to run on GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002045/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu).

How do I use `.cuda()` / `.to()` or something else??
Because I'm running that python from the Notebook cell itself, what should I do  now?

**netflix_data_convert.py**

```
# Copyright (c) 2017 NVIDIA Corporation
from os import listdir, path, makedirs
import random
import sys
import time
import datetime

def print_stats(data):
  total_ratings = 0
  print("STATS")
  for user in data:
    total_ratings += len(data[user])
  print("Total Ratings: {}".format(total_ratings))
  print("Total User count: {}".format(len(data.keys())))

def save_data_to_file(data, filename):
  with open(filename, 'w') as out:
    for userId in data:
      for record in data[userId]:
        out.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(userId, record[0], record[1]))

def create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                  train_min,
                                  train_max,
                                  test_min,
                                  test_max):
  """
  Creates time-based split of NETFLIX data into train, and (validation, test)
  :param all_data:
  :param train_min:
  :param train_max:
  :param test_min:
  :param test_max:
  :return:
  """
  train_min_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(train_min,"%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  train_max_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(train_max, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  test_min_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(test_min, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  test_max_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(test_max, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

  training_data = dict()
  validation_data = dict()
  test_data = dict()

  train_set_items = set()

  for userId, userRatings in all_data.items():
    time_sorted_ratings = sorted(userRatings, key=lambda x: x[2])  # sort by timestamp
    for rating_item in time_sorted_ratings:
      if rating_item[2] >= train_min_ts and rating_item[2] <= train_max_ts:
        if not userId in training_data:
          training_data[userId] = []
        training_data[userId].append(rating_item)
        train_set_items.add(rating_item[0]) # keep track of items from training set
      elif rating_item[2] >= test_min_ts and rating_item[2] <= test_max_ts:
        if not userId in training_data: # only include users seen in the training set
          continue
        p = random.random()
        if p <=0.5:
          if not userId in validation_data:
            validation_data[userId] = []
          validation_data[userId].append(rating_item)
        else:
          if not userId in test_data:
            test_data[userId] = []
          test_data[userId].append(rating_item)

  # remove items not not seen in training set
  for userId, userRatings in test_data.items():
    test_data[userId] = [rating for rating in userRatings if rating[0] in train_set_items]
  for userId, userRatings in validation_data.items():
    validation_data[userId] = [rating for rating in userRatings if rating[0] in train_set_items]

  return training_data, validation_data, test_data


def main(args):
  # create necessary folders:
  for output_dir in [
    "Netflix/N3M_TRAIN", "Netflix/N3M_VALID", "Netflix/N3M_TEST", "Netflix/N6M_TRAIN",
    "Netflix/N6M_VALID", "Netflix/N6M_TEST", "Netflix/N1Y_TRAIN", "Netflix/N1Y_VALID",
    "Netflix/N1Y_TEST", "Netflix/NF_TRAIN", "Netflix/NF_VALID", "Netflix/NF_TEST"]:
    makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

  user2id_map = dict()
  item2id_map = dict()
  userId = 0
  itemId = 0
  all_data = dict()

  folder = args[1]
  out_folder = args[2]

  text_files = [path.join(folder, f)
                for f in listdir(folder)
                if path.isfile(path.join(folder, f)) and ('.txt' in f)]

  for text_file in text_files:
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
      print("Processing: {}".format(text_file))
      lines = f.readlines()
      item = int(lines[0][:-2]) # remove newline and :
      if not item in item2id_map:
        item2id_map[item] = itemId
        itemId += 1

      for rating in lines[1:]:
        parts = rating.strip().split(",")
        user = int(parts[0])
        if not user in user2id_map:
          user2id_map[user] = userId
          userId += 1
        rating = float(parts[1])
        ts = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(parts[2],"%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))
        if user2id_map[user] not in all_data:
          all_data[user2id_map[user]] = []
        all_data[user2id_map[user]].append((item2id_map[item], rating, ts))

  print("STATS FOR ALL INPUT DATA")
  print_stats(all_data)

  # Netflix full
  (nf_train, nf_valid, nf_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                "1999-12-01",
                                                                "2005-11-30",
                                                                "2005-12-01",
                                                                "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix full train")
  print_stats(nf_train)
  save_data_to_file(nf_train, out_folder + "/NF_TRAIN/nf.train.txt")
  print("Netflix full valid")
  print_stats(nf_valid)
  save_data_to_file(nf_valid, out_folder + "/NF_VALID/nf.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix full test")
  print_stats(nf_test)
  save_data_to_file(nf_test, out_folder + "/NF_TEST/nf.test.txt")


  (n3m_train, n3m_valid, n3m_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2005-09-01",
                                                                   "2005-11-30",
                                                                   "2005-12-01",
                                                                   "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix 3m train")
  print_stats(n3m_train)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_train, out_folder+"/N3M_TRAIN/n3m.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 3m valid")
  print_stats(n3m_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_valid, out_folder + "/N3M_VALID/n3m.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 3m test")
  print_stats(n3m_test)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_test, out_folder + "/N3M_TEST/n3m.test.txt")

  (n6m_train, n6m_valid, n6m_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2005-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-11-30",
                                                                   "2005-12-01",
                                                                   "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix 6m train")
  print_stats(n6m_train)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_train, out_folder+"/N6M_TRAIN/n6m.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 6m valid")
  print_stats(n6m_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_valid, out_folder + "/N6M_VALID/n6m.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 6m test")
  print_stats(n6m_test)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_test, out_folder + "/N6M_TEST/n6m.test.txt")

  # Netflix 1 year
  (n1y_train, n1y_valid, n1y_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2004-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-05-31",
                                                                   "2005-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-06-30")
  print("Netflix 1y train")
  print_stats(n1y_train)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_train, out_folder + "/N1Y_TRAIN/n1y.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 1y valid")
  print_stats(n1y_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_valid, out_folder + "/N1Y_VALID/n1y.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 1y test")
  print_stats(n1y_test)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_test, out_folder + "/N1Y_TEST/n1y.test.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

`training_set` (this is the folder under the root directory of `DeepRecommender` folder, `training_set` contains the dataset which I got from [Netflix Dataset](https://academictorrents.com/details/9b13183dc4d60676b773c9e2cd6de5e5542cee9a))

Will this statement do something in favor of what I'm expecting?

`torch.cuda.set_device('cuda:0')`

> `cuda:0` refers to my GPU.

Comment: How does the question differ? See [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using "GPU" as runtime? If so then this question is not a duplicate (not of [*How to make Jupyter...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002045/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu)* at least) and you will have to modify your source code in order to make it work on GPU: yes, you need to use `.to(cuda:i)` or `cuda(i)` where *"i"* is the the *visible* GPU index.

Comment: @Ivan, Yes..
Can u elaborate it? I wanted to know how to run the statements above with cuda.

Comment: `%run ./DeepRecommender/data_utils/netflix_data_convert.py` runs the said script, which can be independent from Jupyter Notebook. You need to modify that script OR look at the specific argument to turn on GPU. That said, from the name `data_convert`, I don't think GPU would give you any significant performance boost, if at all.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code so we can look into it. And we can reopen the post.

Comment: @PeterWood, I think this question slightly differs from "How to make Jupyter Notebook to run on GPU?", which you have mentioned....