# AI - Big Sleep on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, artificial-intelligence

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14392/3652721515.py in <module>
      2 from IPython.display import Image, display
      3 
----> 4 from big_sleep import Imagine
      5 
      6 TEXT = "robot penis" #@param {type:"string"}

d:\ai work\venv\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from big_sleep.big_sleep import BigSleep, Imagine

d:\ai work\venv\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\big_sleep.py in <module>
     24 from big_sleep.clip import load, tokenize
     25 
---> 26 assert torch.cuda.is_available(), 'CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep'
     27 
     28 # graceful keyboard interrupt

AssertionError: CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep
```

Originally big sleep was running on Google Collaboratory but I want to run it on Pycharm. I installed the Jupyter plugin and it run on a website. But the program isnt working because of the CUDA error. I tried researching and I read a forum that said to install CUDA from NVIDIA's website. I did and still nothing so I'm hoping someone can help me fix this issue.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MEWKbm-driRNF8PrU7ogS5o3se-ePyPb?usp=sharing#scrollTo=D2jUsCZXaqcw

Comment: that is the link where its running perfectly on google Collaboratory

Comment: Please confirm you have followed these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002045/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu

Comment: @SanjayManohar What steps do i follow im pretty new to all this?